# restructure identity field in sql server

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a table with identity field of int, i have the following data

```
ID      Name
-------------
1       Item1
4       Item2
9       Item3
....
```

I want to reorder my identity filed like

```
1 Item1
2 Item2
3 Item3
...
```

Comment: The database doesn't care if the values are sequential.  All that matters to it is that the value is unique, for the sake of referential integrity.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot update an existing identity value. Identity_Insert is only for allowing you to specify the identity column with new inserts. 
Your best bet is probably to create a new table with the same definition (including the identity column) and insert all records minus the identity column into the new table. Then drop the old table, and rename the new table with sp_rename. Note that you'll have to drop any foreign keys with this approach.

Comment: As a one-timer, this works.  SELECT into the new table ordering by Name and the IDENTITY columns will come out.  If you have to keep doing this something is seriously wrong with the design, or you have to generate that ID yourself based on some formula.

Comment: I remember there is an option in sql server 2000 named (compact database) or something like that, that do it automatically. but this solution is useful cause i need to do it for one time

Answer (score 0):

One option is to add a new integer field to hold the sequential values, then turn Identity Insert ON for your original column, then migrate the new values over.

Answer (score 0):

One of the limitations of an IDENTITY column in SQL Server is that it cannot be updated directly. The best option is probably to create a new table.

In general, if you care about the ordering of values then don't use IDENTITY because it's too difficult to control the ordering. Use a regular column instead. SQL Server 2011 onwards supports sequences which give you much more control and don't require the target column to be read-only.